# Will I be able to complete Inferno without a group?

Tags: diablo-iii

It looks like Inferno is going to be pretty hard. ([discussion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEoR2pS7DXc&t=54m33s) about the inferno difficulty. It starts at 54:33 and lasts about 2 min)

My question is whether this difficulty is supposed to be feasible in solo, or will you absolutely need a group to solve it?  If so, will it still be easier to do it as a group? I can imagine monsters with very strong resistances, so having a group can bring flexibility in your style of combat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the game is designed around being a single player game with the added option of multiplayer.

That being said a coordinated team will do better due to being able to combine different classes together. This is from [a video](http://www.ign.com/videos/2012/05/06/diablo-iii-blizzards-top-tips-for-inferno-mode) where Jay Wilson gives tips for inferno mode.

Update: First person to beat Diablo on Inferno did it solo, so it is definitely possible. [source](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/42866-i-beat-diablo-inferno-solo/)

Comment: You found the exact references I was about to answer myself. Great job!

Comment: Now the question becomes whether the time you invest building a group is going to pay off at the later stages of the game. My bet would be that it will.

Comment: yes, it defently looks like it is going to be about building a group if you want efficient Inferno runs. But that being said it should be rather easy to create a good group, there is no cost of respecing, getting to max level looks to be rather easy(compare to the grind of max level in D2) and items don't bind. The main concern is getting the items for multiple sets so you can cover multiple roles depending on what friends you got online or what you run in to.

Comment: The good part is that: "The loot will not be focused on the boss only" * - *

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it has been stated [by Jay Wilson of Blizzard](http://www.diablofans.com/news/1174-unlock-6-the-order-jay-wilson-qas-zarhym-on-pvp-blue-posts/) that Inferno will be soloable, and yes, being in a group will make it easier:

> **Many players are discussing about the Inferno Difficulty since Diablo 2’s Hell just had reduced resistances and that was it. Will there be any type of special feature just for the inferno mode? Also can you solo it?**
>
> It will be a lot different from Hell mode in Diablo 2, such as a monster creating a wall to stop the player from fleeing from the monster or blocking off ranged attacks with the use of the wall. The AI will move significantly different also you will be able to solo it even though the difficulty will be a bit easier with co-op it is not a must.