# What is the highest difficulty that can reasonably be soloed?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will I be able to complete Inferno without a group?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65010/will-i-be-able-to-complete-inferno-without-a-group)

I'm not much of a group player in Diablo, having finished both 1 and 2 solo with multiple characters.  I've read a couple of comments from Blizzard indicating that group play is almost expected in later difficulties.  What's the highest difficulty that is soloable?  What has been soloed so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All difficulties can be soloed. At least nightmare is still pretty easy.

The fact that even inferno is soloable was also confirmed by a blizzard staff member:

> Jay also states that it is absolutely possible to solo Inferno since they didn't design it to require cooperative play, however a well coordinated group will most likely perform better. <sup>[[source]](http://www.diablowiki.net/Inferno#The_New_Difficulty_Level)</sup>